# Install app from PKG file is not visible in Application

Tags: xamarin.mac

I have mac project in Xamarin.Forms and I had created .pkg file in release mode (set the provisioning profile for code sign and product sign properly) but when I am install application from created PKG file then it installed successfully but I am not able see it in application list or in launchpad. I am using same mac machine to generate PKG file and for install purpose.

Where app is installed if it is not installed in application folder. where should I look?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6814/create-installer-package-gt-pkg-but-that-pkg-does-not-do-anything-useful) on Xamarin Forums, the `.pkg` installer should still contain your application and work properly on another machine or VM.

As a workaround you can try:

> 1. execute: sudo pkgutil --forget < package_id >
> 2. delete all < app_name >.app bundles on the machine
> 3. install your app package and check Applications folder

You can also try

> 1. move the .pkg out of the bin/Release (or bin/Debug) folder
> 2. clean the bin/Release (or bin/Debug) folder
> 3. try to install .pkg from new location